# could not determine kind of name for C.getnameinfo in go when running the go build

Tags: c, go

so i've just upgrade my go version to the higher version which go1.20.2
previously i use go1.18.x.

And i already update the environment path for go

```bash
export GOPATH="$HOME/go";
export GOROOT="$HOME/.go"; 
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH";
```

So, everytime when i tried to go build always shows these error

```bash
/home/usr/.go/src/net/cgo_resnew.go:21:17: could not determine kind of name for C.getnameinfo
```

I've been searching for the answer but i don't get it from internet.
Does anyone knows, what makes this error is?

when do this

```bash
go build .
```

it should no show this errors

```
/home/usr/.go/src/net/cgo_resnew.go:21:17: could not determine kind of name for C.getnameinfo
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `CGO_ENABLED` on golang environment using command `go env`. if your value `CGO_ENABLED` is **1**, you have to set value into **0**. Add `export CGO_ENABLED=0` on your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc if you using zsh (I recommend added environment variable on ~/.profile to set globally)